# terra not reading .nc files (GDAL error 4)

Tags: r, spatial, netcdf, terra, ncdf4

I'm trying to open a .nc file with terra, but I'm getting the following error:

```
'' not recognised as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)
```

Reproducible example here (16mb nc file):

```
if (!file.exists("HadISST_ice.nc")) { 
     download.file("https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/HadISST_ice.nc.gz","HadISST_ice.nc.gz")
     R.utils:::gunzip("HadISST_ice.nc.gz")
}
library(terra)
hadISST <- rast('HadISST_ice.nc')
```

The file opens with raster::brick, but not with terra:rast, which if I understand correctly from @robert-hijmnan [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413105/terrarast-vs-rasterbrick-for-loading-in-nc-files) is because raster uses ncdf4 while terra uses GDAL.

In GDAL the .nc file opens with no issues via terminal:

```
 % gdalinfo HadISST_ice.nc

Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: HadISST_ice.nc
Size is 512, 512
```

But I can't read the file with terra without throwing a GDAL error 4. Session info below:

```
print(sessionInfo())
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] terra_1.5-34

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0   tools_4.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.8.3     codetools_0.2-18
```

and GDAL:

```
% gdal-config --version
GDAL 3.5.0, released 2022/05/10
```

Answer (score 4):

edit: the problem seems to be related to be a MacOS specific issue with terra not being installed with netCDF drivers:

[R terra gdal version incorrect, cannot read .nc (GDAL error 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599324/r-terra-gdal-version-incorrect-cannot-read-nc-gdal-error-4)

installing the development version of terra solves the problem:

`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev’)`

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution to your own question. I can confirm that this worked for me as of March, 2023. I am now running terra V1.7-19 on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1 and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible cause of the error 4 with `terra` package which I have just experienced:

If you have downloaded multiple .nc files from the web through R in Windows make sure to use `mode = "wb"` in the function argument

```
download.file(url = "https://example/xx.nc", destfile = "/example.nc", mode = "wb")
```