# R terra gdal version incorrect, cannot read .nc (GDAL error 4)

Tags: r, gis, gdal, r-sf, terra

I have several issues with terra and it's connection to GDAL.
I installed terra v. 1.6.7 in R v. 4.2.1 on a Mac running Big Sur v. 11.6.8

I installed GDAL 3.2.2 from [www.kyngchaos.com](http://www.kyngchaos.com), located in HD/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.Framework

**Issue 1: terra reports wrong GDAL version**

```
gdal()
#[1] "3.4.2"
```

There is no GDAL 3.4.2 on my system (afaik).

Relatedly, `gdal(lib = "proj")` gives `"8.2.1"` but I have PROJ 7.2.1 installed.

**Issue 2: terra cannot read NetCDF files**

```
r1 <- rast("~/Downloads/soiltemp1.nc")
#Error: [rast] cannot read from /Users/db/Downloads/soiltemp1.nc 
#Warning message: 
#'/Users/db/Downloads/soiltemp1.nc' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)
```

whereas in terminal `gdalinfo ~/Downloads/soiltemp1.nc`

gives correct information on file contents.

**Issue 3: terra does not list NetCDF drivers in GDAL**

In R
`gdal(drivers = TRUE)`

the resulting report does not include NetCDF drivers

**Issue 4: Cannot install terra from Github**

`remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")`

exits with error `configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.`

whereas proj_api.h is present in HD/Library/Frameworks/PROJ.framework/Headers/

**Issue 5: sf also finds wrong Framework versions**

Relatedly, `library(sf)` reports `Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE`

Any clues as to what is going on, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

> Issue 1: terra reports wrong GDAL version

You have installed a binary package from CRAN. The versions of GDAL/PROJ that the package was built with are reported (and used). It does not matter what version of GDAL you may have installed on your system (if any).

I have installed "terra" on MacOS, using R 4.2.1 and the "r-release (x86_64)" CRAN binary version of terra 1.6-7 (that is, I am not using the "arm64" version). Can you confirm that you are using that version? As expected, I get the same version numbers as you do:

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6-7
gdal(lib="")
#   gdal    proj    geos 
#"3.4.2" "8.2.1" "3.10.2"
```

> Issue 2: terra cannot read NetCDF files
> Issue 3: terra does not list NetCDF drivers in GDAL

I also see that

```
d <- gdal(drivers=TRUE)
d[d$name=="netCDF", ]
#[1] name      type      can       vsi       long.name
#<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Where I would expect what I get on windows:

```
d[d$name=="netCDF", ]
#     name   type        can   vsi                  long.name
#91 netCDF raster read/write FALSE Network Common Data Format
```

So the package was built without the netCDF plug-in. netCDF is a fundamentally important file format for spatial data and this is a major problem that should be brought to the attention of CRAN.

A work-around is to install the *development version* of terra from the R universe, like this:
`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev’)`

> Issue 4: Cannot install terra from Github

See the suggestions for installing from source (using brew) on the github sites of [terra](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) and [sf](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf) or elsewhere. Problems mostly arise if dependencies are not in the expected path (note the use of "configure.args" to deal with that); or if there are multiple installations of GDAL.

Comment: Thank you for your help, apologies for my ignorance on these matters. I'll report the lack of netCDF drivers to CRAN.

Comment: I confirm that I'm using terra 1.6-7 and that gdal() reports the gdal, proj and geos version numbers you list.